# SwipeRefreshLayout not working

Tags: android, android-widget, android-support-library

I'm using `SwipeRefreshListener` from the support libraries.  I am calling `setRefresh` from `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` of my `AsyncTask`.  However, nothing changes, there is no animation.  Is there something that I'm missing?  Are there certain setup parameters I need to set in order for it to work properly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has worked for me, see more here: http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/

**SwipeRefreshLayout: The layout**
you only need to decorate the swipable content (probable the whole layout) with this new layout. This view must be scrollable, such a ScrollView or a ListView. As a simple example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**The code**
We just need to get the layout, and assign some colours and the listener. The refreshing listener is a post delayed handler.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, 
                android.R.color.holo_green_light, 
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light, 
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    }


    @Override public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't know SwipeRefreshLayout works only as parent of swipeable views thank you

Answer (score 5):

//Please check this answers it hepls me :
//[SwipeRefreshLayout setRefreshing() not showing indicator initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858692/swiperefreshlayout-setrefreshing-not-showing-//indicator-initially)
//especially this

```
  mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    } 
  });
```